# what is the better way of delete items from objects using java script

Tags: javascript, performance, javascript-objects

I have 50000 rows and 200 columns(on each row) and trying to delete all col objects from each row object, now it's taking 5 seconds to complete entire process. Is there any better way to improve performance?
Note : There is chance of skip some objects, in this case don't delete skipRows and skipCols objects.

```
var skipRows = {10:1,11:1,12:1,13:1,14:1,15:1,16:1,17:1,18:1,19:1,20:1};
var skipCols = {50:1,51:1,52:1,53:1,54:1,55:1,56:1,57:1,58:1,59:1,60:1};

for(var i = 0; i < 50000; i++){
   if(!(i in skipRows)){
    var rowObject = rowColObjects[i];
     for  ( var j = 0; j < 200; j++){
        if(!(j in skipCols)){
          delete rowObject[i+"-"+j];
        }
     } 
  }
```

}

below is the fiddle to see sample code and results :

http://jsfiddle.net/rambabu14/9mcne3en/

Thanks,
Rambabu.

Comment: from your description, `rowColObjects=[]` should work just fine.

Comment: @georg You meant  `rowColObjects={}`?

Comment: i mean var rowColObjects = {};   sample code for adding objects :var rowColObjects = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < 50000; i++){
     var rowObjects = {
                       id : i,
                       name : "rowObject"+i 
              };
     for(var j = 0; j < 200; j++){
      rowObjects[i+"-"+j] = {
                        id : j,
                        name : "colObject"+j 
               };
     }
     rowColObjects[i] = rowObjects;
    }

Comment: It took 5 secs because you iterate the `50000` elements of the object.

Comment: @georg thank you for replying, but i want to skip some objects for delete operation.

Comment: @RambabuPudi: edit your question then, as it stands it's confusing.

Comment: @WisnuAdiNurcahyo, If we comment delete operation, it's taking 8ms to complete loop iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Why not to reinitialize it, instead of traversing all the keys and deleting them.

`rowColObjects = {};`

See the performance here http://jsfiddle.net/9mcne3en/3/

Comment: there is a condition before delete objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip some objects from deletion, then

```
for(var i = 0; i < 50000; i++){
   var rowObject = rowColObjects[i];
   if (condition)
   {
      rowObject = {};
   }
}
```

Comment: we need to place condition deleting columns objects, updated question properly.

Answer (score 0):

In my browser (current latest Firefox), your original code took about 14 secs. Then, I'm trying to using my code and it takes about 6 secs. At least, my code improves the execution time.

```
const newObj = Object.keys(rowColObjects)
  .reduce((acc, row) => {
    acc[row] = {
      id: rowColObjects[row].id,
      name: rowColObjects[row].name,
      ...Object.keys(rowColObjects[row])
        .slice(2)
        .reduce((acc2, col, i) => {
          if (i % 2 !== 0) acc2[col] = rowColObjects[row][col];

          return acc2;
        }, {})
    };

    return acc;
  }
  , {});
```

Another way is to store *remain* id in the another variable.

```
const newObj = Object.keys(rowColObjects)
  .reduce((acc, row) => {
    acc[rowColObjects[row].id] = Object.keys(rowColObjects[row])
      .slice(2)
      .filter((_, i) => i % 2 !== 0);

    return acc;
  }, {});
```

It is super fast. Took about 2 secs only. Then, you could create a mechanism to store the remain items back to an object.

Comment: Thank you wisnu, Can you please update in below fiddle, skiprows and skipCols will change dynamically, http://jsfiddle.net/rambabu14/91h1uaL9/    I am using chrome and IE

Comment: Thank you all , this issue was fixed by adding only required objects istead of deleting all objects. below is the jsfiddle :  http://jsfiddle.net/rambabu14/g0mjgfgq/

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.keys(rowColObjects).forEach(key => {
    const rowObject = rowColObjects[key]
    Object.keys(rowObject).forEach(colKey => {
        if(!['id', 'name'].includes(colKey)) {
            delete rowObject[colKey]
        }
    })
})
```